# @font-face text blocky on ie8 - live example

Tags: internet-explorer, fonts, internet-explorer-8, font-face

I have embedded @font-face fonts correctly as far as I can tell (I have checked and double checked), yet I have strange behavior on IE8 that I have never experienced before.

On IE8, there is a flash of the fonts perfectly rendered and then they switch to be awfully blocky. They work fine in all other browsers (IE9+, Webkit etc.)

This is the site in question: http://scope-art.com/

I am serving eot fonts correctly as such:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'proxima';
    src: url('../fonts/proxima_nova_bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/proxima_nova_bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/proxima_nova_bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/proxima_nova_bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/proxima_nova_bold-webfont.svg#proxima_nova_rgbold') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Can anyone explain what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply an EOT version of your font in order for IE8 to embed it. 
This may be why it's not working as you want it to.

You can try [Font Squirrel @font-face Generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) as a tool to prepare font-face code.

Comment: Thanks for your response. See edit above, I am serving EOT fonts. There is a flash of the correct font and then it goes blocky.